# How to apply a AR(MA) model to a prewhitened signal?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I have two (vehicle velocity) signals that should consist of similar "latent" drivers, but have different autocorrelation structures. The driver-signals are quite nasty statistically, so I'm not attempting to model them.

I can get quite nice results by prewhitening the signals using AR(1)-residuals, but these are very difficult to interpret in "real world terms" (ie. velocities). So what I'd like to do is to prewhiten one of the signals and then add the AR-model of the *other* signal to this, so that I'd have two signals with same autocorrelation structures.

It may be that there is a very simple method for doing this, but unfortunately I haven't found one. I guess it should be sort of an inverse of the Yule-Walker method. One also that is quite close is to use arima.sim with innovations, but with the difference that I don't have innovations, but residuals.

Comment: This is really more of a statistics question than a programming question.  It's better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, I added the question to stats.stackexchange.com. Should this one be deleted?

Comment: @jampekka best practice, if you're not sure if it's "programming" or "stats" question is to identify to people that a) it was cross-posted and b) where it is (the link).

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19568/how-to-apply-an-arma-model-to-a-prewhitened-signal

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do and I'm not sure what you mean by "add the AR-model". However, here is some direction:

1. You could fit an ARMA model to one dataset and then write your own down to use those coefficients on another dataset.
2. Take a look at the `forecast` package and the function `Arima()` and `auto.arima()`. There is also R's `arima()`.

Comment: What I meant is in essence the number 1. I already applied the autoregression model by using it as an IIR-filter, but it's quite sensitive to outliers. But that may very well be unavoidable due to the nature of the autoregression.